# log determinant jacobian in Normalizing Flow training with Pytorch

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, generative-adversarial-network, image-generation

I am studying how to train a normalizing flow model from the below tutorial,

- https://uvadlc-notebooks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial_notebooks/tutorial11/NF_image_modeling.html#Normalizing-Flows-on-images
- In Dequantization part, the **log determinant jacobian (ldj)** is being calculated as `0 -log(256) * (28*28*1)`.

  - I cannot understand this ldj calculation. How are ldj set to 0 initially, and why the ldj is being calculated in this way?
    [image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Note that `1-sel.alpha` is the derivative of the scaling operation, thus the Jacobian of this operation is a diagonal matrix with `z.shape[1:]` entries on the diagonal, thus the Jacobian determinant is simply the product of these diagonal entries which gives rise to

```
ldj += np.log(1-self.alpa) * np.prod(z.shape[1:])
```

the second line accounts for the log determinant of the sigmoid $s(z)$ function as $s'(z)=s(z)(1-s(z))$. So the two lines result from the application of the chain rule which turns into a sum when taking the logarithm.

Setting `ldj = torch.zeros(1,)` is just the initialization of this variable - its value will be only updated in the module. Not sure what the motivation is, but it could be that they want to apply the dequant_module for each individual sample in the batch.